# How do I prove the norm of this linear functional is $2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

$f$ is defined on $C[-1, 1]$ by $$f(x)=\int_{-1}^0 x(t) dt - \int_0^1 x(t) dt.$$

I can show that $\|f\| \le 2$. I don't know how to show $\|f\| \ge 2$.

Comment: do you have the sup norm on $C[-1,1]$?

Comment: @Giovanni No, max norm. I'm assuming. This is not given in the problem.

Comment: Max and sup norm are the same on compact sets (since continuous functions always achieve their maximum).

Comment: @CameronWilliams You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Of course if you can plug in

$$x(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t\in [-1, 0] \\ -1 & \text{if } t\in (0,1]\end{cases}$$

Then this function satifies $f(x) = 2$. But this $x$ is not continuous. However you can approximate this by $x_n \in C([-1,1])$, where

$$x_n (t) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } t\in [-1, -\frac 1n)\\
-1 & \text{if } t\in (\frac 1n, 1]\\ 
 - nx & \text{if } t\in [-\frac 1n, \frac 1n] 
\end{cases}$$

Then $\|x_n\| = 1$ and 
$$f(x_n) =  1- \frac 1n + \frac 1{2n} + 1- \frac 1n + \frac 1{2n} = 2 - \frac{1}{n}$$

Thus $\|f\| \ge 2- \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.